# Pandas how to add additional values between two row-values in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a melted data frame. Under the same index, I have "early_date" & "latest_date", which are in "int" dtype. I want to create additional values in between the "early_date" & "latest_date" row-values. Incidentally, I want to stack the generated values into new rows between them.

For example, under 5021 index, I want to add a Middle value between "early_date" & "latest_date" --> 201729 & 201731. And the Middle value will be under the same index 5021, and it is simply 201730 .

However, the gap between "early_date" & "latest_date" may vary within 5. For example, under the same index, "early_date" & "latest_date" --> 201730 & 201733. Then, the Middle values that I need to insert will be 201731 & 201732.

Are there any ways to perform this operation? * The index (date) can be ignored

[image]

[image]

[image: This is the original dataframe, I want to split "VOL" evenly between the date range of "early_date" & "latest_date". E.g. I want to spread the VOL =2 to 2/3 when the "early_date" & "latest_date" == 201729 & 201731]

This is the original dataframe, I want to split "VOL" evenly between the date range of "early_date" & "latest_date". E.g. In index 5021, I want to spread the VOL from 2 to 2/3 when the "early_date" & "latest_date" ==  201729 & 201731. Also show 201730 in the dataframe

Comment: You say that `date` column can be ignored, but in your example, `date` seems to be the index, not just any column.
Instead of pictures, I think you should insert the original DataFrame, and the DataFrame that you would want to obtain, as code blocks, so they can easily be copy-pasted by anybody who wants to help.

Comment: Yes, it is the index

Comment: @kelvin.aaa2 can we see the data frame before you melt it? `df.head(10).to_dict()` and paste the results in question.

Comment: Hi Chris, I posted the orginal df as the 3rd picture, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC

## Sample data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'index': [1,1,2,2,3,3],
                   'variable': ['early_date', 'late_date']*3,
                   'value': [123,124,125,127,128,129]})

# This is what your data looks like unmelted
df_p = df.pivot('index', 'variable', 'value').reset_index()
df_p.columns.name = ''
```

## use pop with explode

```
# set the index column as the index of the frame
df_p = df_p.set_index('index')

# use list comprehension with zip and pop to create a range
df_p['new'] = [list(range(x,y+1)) for x, y in zip(df_p.pop('early_date'), df_p.pop('late_date'))]
# explode new column
df_p['new'].explode()

index
1    123
1    124
2    125
2    126
2    127
3    128
3    129
```